# Map loop javascript in function not returning desired value

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains objects that looks like this.

```
const arr = [
    {
        value: -1,
        label: "None"
    },
    {
        value: 24*60*60,
        label: "24 hours"
    },
    {
        value: 7*24*60*60,
        label: "7 days"
    },
    {
        value: 30*24*60*60,
        label: "1 month"
    },
    {
        value: 90*24*60*60,
        label: "3 months"
    }
];
```

I have the below function which 'kind of' works, but it is not returning the value. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

The following is a react method

```
class Test extends Component { 

    ......

   getLabelFromValue(arr, value) {

      arr.forEach((item) => {

        if(item.value === value) {

            return item.label;

        }


    });

}

const value = getLabelFromValue(arr, 86400); //value is equal to undefined
```

Comment: You array is not valid. is value a String ?

Comment: `getLabelFromValue(arr, value) {` should be `function getLabelFromValue(arr, value) {`

Comment: You are using `forEach` and not `map` and not returning anything frm `getLabelFromValue`?

Comment: What do you need as the output ?

Comment: @lonut it depends if the extract was taken from a class

Comment: @TryingToImprove, he updated the OP. He originally had `map`. Callum Linington, yes, but, in the case provided in the OP, does not apply.

Comment: @Ionut apologies, it is a class method from react.

Comment: @Andreas thanks! would you like to put that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Callum Linington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42714290/402037) has already given a short explanation and solution how to solve the problem with your `.forEach()` construct.

Based on the code, `getLabelFromValue` should return a single value only.
Hence I would use another method of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) -> [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

*"The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned."*

```
getLabelFromValue(arr, value) {
    let item = arr.find(i => i.value === value);
    return item ? item.label : undefined /* or any other default value... */;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning from the `forEach` not the outer function:

```
getLabelFromValue(arr, value) {
    let label;
    let done = false;

    arr.forEach(item => {

        if(item.value === value && !done) {

            label = item.label;

            done = true;

        }


    });

    return label;
}

const value = getLabelFromValue(arr, 86400); //value is equal to undefined
```

I would personally just use filter.

```
arr.filter(item => item.value === value)[0]; // OR
arr.find(item => item.value === value);
```